# When copying code, U+00a0 (nbsp) characters creating problem with VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my Ubuntu machine recently i have installed vs code. But when i try to paste any code copied from php.net website all the spaces and tabs are replaced by "U+00a0 (nbsp) characters"
[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFaTm.png)

Currently i'm doing: using Regular Expression (.*) and search for the unicode character with regex [\xa0] and replace by space. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: My guess is that that's actually an issue with the source where you copy from: can you link to a specific page where you copied code from?

Comment: It just happen with any page i copy from [php.net](https://www.php.net) website.

Comment: Yeah, and we don't know any one you've tried. So please **link to a specific one** so we can try to reproduce the issue. Why is that so hard!

Comment: Ok consider [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) as an example.

Comment: Inspect the code samples: they **do** have `&nbsp;` in all the places that look like blanks. That is U+00A0, so the copy-paste can't really do anything other than copy that. Doing anything else would be "lying" to you about what you just copied. You can try find some plugin that automatically does this kind of replacement for you or continue the Search&Replace that you're currently doing. In other words: VScode behaves correctly here. It's the website that does silly things.